# How to draw a power curve using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use `ggplot2` to visualize some data that follows a power curve. This has been asked before ([Add exp/power trend line to a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528631/add-exp-power-trend-line-to-a-ggplot)) but the answer didn't really help.

One trick is to use `stat_function()` to create a curve. However, I am unable to get  `stat_function()` and my power curve to work with logarithmic scales.

I illustrate my problems.

Create some sample data and a base plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- 1:100
pwr <- function(x)x^-2.5
dat <- data.frame(x, y = pwr(x))

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()

p + stat_function(fun = pwr)
```

[image]

Great, let's add some logaritmic scales using a `coord_trans()`.  This works perfectly, except that my straight lines are no longer straight (exactly as the documentation tells me to expect).

```
p + stat_function(fun = pwr) + coord_trans(x = "log10", y = "log10")
```

[image]

So, try again with `coord_x_log10()` and `coord_y_log10()`, but this **throws an error**:

```
p + stat_function(fun = pwr) + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()

Error in seq.default(min, max, by = by) : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

This has most likely to do with the fact that I have to adjust my function to invert the effect of the scales, but I can't quite figure it out.

I can do it with only the logarithmix x-scale:

```
p + scale_x_log10() + stat_function(fun = function(x)pwr(10^x))
```

[image]

I have no idea how to convert the y-values if I add `scale_y_log10()`.

**I'm probably missing something fundamental. Is there an easy way to plot this curve?**

Comment: If the `ggplot2` part isn't a deal-breaker, there is a package, `poweRlaw`, that does this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/index.html.

Comment: Silly question: do `geom_line()` in addition to `geom_point()` with the original data and don't use `stat_function` at all...?

Comment: Two problems: You need to set axis limits in order to avoid zero/negative values. E.g., `scale_x_log10(limits = c(1, 200)) + scale_y_log10(limits = c(1e-5, 1))`. However, `stat_function` doesn't work together with axis transformation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382032/ggplot2-scale-x-log10-destroys-doesnt-apply-for-function-plotted-via-stat-fun

Comment: @Roland I tinkered with setting the limits manually as well, but I wondered how useful that is in general if you don't know exactly what your data will do...

Comment: @joran You could also use `scale_x_log10(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_log10(expand = c(0,0))`. However, if your data can be zero/negative the transformation simply is not appropriate.

Comment: It seems to me like you're calling pwr() twice, on the same data. `stat_function(fun = pwr)` maps the y-aesthetic. But you've already created the y-aesthetic as `pwr`. So wouldn't you just want the `identity`? It's like you're plotting `y = pwr(pwr(x))`. I think removing stat_function in your second call ought to give you the straight line you would expect (with spacing).

Comment: @Roland Your suggestion of limiting the y-scale is indeed very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I'm doing this deliberately. The `geom_point()` uses the data frame to plot the points. The `stat_function()` doesn't touch the underlying data, but only uses the function. I don't believe these interfere at all.

Comment: `ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + coord_trans(ytrans = "log10", xtrans = "log10")`... isn't that what you want though?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen In fact that isn't what I want. In the real case I plot some real data using `geom_point()` and a fitted line using `stat_function()`.  I want both, but they don't fit exactly as in the sample data.

Comment: @Andrie Have you tried using `stat_smooth` with `method = "nls"` (or whichever method you use for fitting)?

Comment: @Roland So my situation is this: I have a network graph that I analyse with igraph. igraph contains functions to estimate the power curve coefficient (subject to the assumption that the power curve is only a power curve in a certain range of the data). Now I simply want to display this line as a straight line on the log-log plot. I suspect what you mean is use `nls()` to do the estimate. I haven't tried that. Will give it a go. Meanwhile, your suggestion to limit the y-scale probably answers my question.  Perhaps you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: One funny thing, if you change `n` in `stat_function()`, it works up to `n<=20`. So for example `p + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10() + stat_function(n=20, fun = pwr)` works but not as nice as you expect :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting my comments into an answer:

The main problem is a bug in `stat_function`. When used in conjunction with axis transformations it calculates y-values from the transformed and not from the original values. This has been [fixed on github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1011) very recently.

However, this is not easy to see since the first error occurs when calculating the axis breaks since the bug produces `Inf`, zero and/or negative y-values. You need to set explicit axis limits to see that the actual problem is `stat_function`:

```
p + stat_function(fun = pwr) + 
  scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10(limits = c(1e-5, 1))
#Warning message:
#Removed 100 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image: resulting plot]

It's even more obvious if you only transform the x-axis:

```
p + stat_function(fun = pwr) + 
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image: resulting plot]

If you can't use the ggplot2 version from github you could use this:

```
p + geom_line(data = data.frame(x = seq(min(dat$x), max(dat$x), length.out = 100)),
              aes(y = pwr(x))) + 
  scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
```

[image: resulting plot]